# How can I get a value from a custom field e put into a custom shipping method?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to calculate my shipping rate from value that users put in a extra field that I added on shipping area form. I added a custom field called 'district' and created a custom method of shipping extending WC_Shipping_Method using this turtorial [Create a Custom Shipping Method for WooCommerce](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-shipping-method-for-woocommerce--cms-26098/).

But the author are using values from `$country = $package["destination"]["country"];` and in package you can just use country, state, city and zip code. I've tryed using `$country = $package["destination"]["ciry"];` and it's worked but when I try to use my custom field nothing happed.

How get a value from my custom field 'district' to use in my custom method?

I saw this question [Wordpress Woocommerce get value from custom shipping field (AJAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353727/wordpress-woocommerce-get-value-from-custom-shipping-field-ajax/) but I don't figured out how they are passed the value from form. And i've tried use this:

`WC()->checkout->get_value('district')`

from this question [Get fields from checkout form into calculate_shipping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434437/get-fields-from-checkout-form-into-calculate-shipping/) but does go on not working.

This is my custom field

```
// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {

  $fields['billing']['district'] = array(
    'label'     => __('Bairro', 'woocommerce'),
    'type'      => 'text',
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
  );

  $fields['shipping']['district'] = array(
    'label'     => __('Bairro', 'woocommerce'),
    'type'      => 'text',
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
  );

  return $fields;
}
```

And this is my custom shipping method

```
function my_custom_shipping_init() {
    class my_custom_shipping_method extends WC_Shipping_Method {

        public function __construct() {
            $this->id = 'my_custom_shipping';
            $this->method_title = __('Taxa de entregas por bairros', 'my-custom-shipping');
            $this->enabled = 'yes';
            $this->title = __('Taxa de entregas por bairros', 'my-custom-shipping');
            $this->method_description = __('Plugin to calculate My Custom Shipping Cost', 'my-custom-shipping');
        }

        function calculate_shipping( $pakage = array() ) {
            $shipping_cost = 0;
            $destination_district = WC()->checkout->get_value( 'district' );
            switch($destination_district){
                case 'Guaramirim': $shipping_cost = 5; break;
                case 'Beta': $shipping_cost = 7; break;
            }
            $this->add_rate(array('id'        => 'my_custom_shipping',
                                            'label'     => 'Taxa de Entrega',
                                            'cost'      => $shipping_cost,
                                            'taxes'     => '',
                                            'calc_tax'  => 'per_order'));
        }           
    } 
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_shipping_init', 'my_custom_shipping_init' );
function my_custom_shipping_method( $methods )  {
    $methods[] = 'my_custom_shipping_method';
    return $methods;
}
```

If I let my function like this:

```
function calculate_shipping( $pakage = array() ) {
            $shipping_cost = 0;
            $destination_district = $package["destination"]["city"];
            switch($destination_district){
                case 'Guaramirim': $shipping_cost = 5; break;
                case 'Beta': $shipping_cost = 7; break;
            }
            $this->add_rate(array('id'        => 'my_custom_shipping',
                                            'label'     => 'Taxa de Entrega',
                                            'cost'      => $shipping_cost,
                                            'taxes'     => '',
                                            'calc_tax'  => 'per_order'));
        }
```

it's works well with the values Guaramirim and Beta in city field but I don't wanna use any default field I need use a custom field.